# Xamarin C# : SendPingAsync() throws an exception (object reference not instantiated)

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, mono, ping

System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.SendPingAsync() throws an exception when running (object reference not instantiated).

```
                Ping ping = new Ping();
                PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(__IPADDRBOX,400);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    break;
                }
```

This bug from MONO is known and was fixed few weeks ago : [https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/2984][1]
How can I fix this bug in my project ? Should I rebuild System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll ? How ?

(I'm using latest Xamarin.Forms packages and VS 2015.)

Comment: I don't know how to resolve it, but im facing the same issue. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: No way with SendPingAsync, unfortunatly.
My goal was to check if my cloud server is avaiable, so I just connect to it directly with ConnectAsync().